# .NET MVC StackOverflow exception after returning View

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow

I'm getting a 'System.StackOverflowException' in my .NET MVC project after the View has been sent to the Client.  The View renders correctly, so the Client side sees no error.  However, the server crashes with the StackOverflow Exception afterwards.  I've only tested this in IISExpress/VisualStudio, not in IIS.

I have html files on a remote server.  I'm loading the html files like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient() 
{Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password)})
{
    string html = client.DownloadString(url);
    viewModel.Pages.Add(html);
}
```

Where 'Pages' can contain multiple html pieces.  However, the test page I'm using is a full html page, with "doctype", "head", "body", etc. nodes.

In my View, I'm rendering the page like this:

```
foreach(var page in Model.Pages)
{
    @Html.Raw(page)
}
```

As I said, the page renders correctly, but the server crashes afterwards.  I don't see any recursive calls being made.  I tried to use Debug Diag tool to troubleshoot, but couldn't get any crashdumps to populate.

Also, if I render the 'page' without the @Html.Raw() the crash doesn't occur ( However, the page then doesn't render correctly.  e.g. the LT/GT brackets are replaced by "& gt;" / "& lt;", among other characters )

I suspect that it may have something to do with the length of the 'html' string, or the content of the page.  I have another sitemap page that is simpler, loads correctly, and doesn't cause the server error.

The exceptions are occurring in different places as well: System.Web.dll, mscorlib.dll, and System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

How can I troubleshoot this StackOverflow Exception?

Is there a limit on the size of an string that can be rendered with @Html.Raw()?

External Stack Trace:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonWriter.HasOpenAttribute.get() Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonWriter.WriteState.get()   Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonWriter.WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)    Unknown
>       System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(string localName, string value)    Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonWriterDelegator.WriteInt(int value)  Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.IntDataContract.WriteXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator writer, object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)   Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.WriteJsonValueCore(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator jsonWriter, object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson context, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)   Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.WriteDataContractValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool verifyKnownType, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, System.Type declaredType)    Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.SerializeWithXsiType(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, System.Type objectType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, System.Type declaredType) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)  Unknown
>       [Lightweight Function]
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.WriteJsonValueCore(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator jsonWriter, object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson context, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.WriteDataContractValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract dataContract, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool verifyKnownType, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, System.Type declaredType)    Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.SerializeWithXsiType(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, System.Type objectType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, System.Type declaredType) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)  Unknown

The portion from [Lightweight Function] to the end repeats until the crash.

Edit:

Just found this error (among others) on the Output window: A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: What does the full stack trace look like?

Comment: I do see recursion on the external stack trace: [Lightweight Function]; WriteJsonValueCore(); WriteDataContractValue(); SerializeWithoutXsiType(); WriteContext.InternalSerialize(); WriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(); REPEAT ( wasn't sure how best to show the stack trace in a comment )

Comment: Can you show us the stack trade, just [edit] it in to the question.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but I had the same problem and it was caused by invalid html I was adding to the page. So maybe your pages were also html invalid - just to let others know.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Trying to display the contents of a large log file via Html.Raw(). The stack trace ends in System.Web.HttpResponseUnmanagedBufferElement.HttpResponseUnmanagedBufferElement()

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by returning 'Content' instead of 'View(model)'.

Previously, I was adding the html string to a ViewModel and rendering the page by returning:

```
return View(model);
```

When I changed the return to Content, the server did not crash.

```
return Content(htmlString);
```